# Deserialize to another version of Sitecore

Tags: sitecore

I am looking at serialising objects in Sitecore v6.1 and deserialising to Sitecore v6.6, I have found a lot of information about serialisation but not to different versions of Sitecore.  Has anyone had experience with this before, and if so were there any issues?

If there are any changes in required format I am considering writing a script to update the individual serialised Sitecore items.

Comment: This might not be an answer, as I haven't used serialize that much. But I've worked quite a bit with Packages and I haven't run into any problems using packages from different versions, other that the syntax for the security changed somewhere between Sitecore 5 og Sitecore 6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I haven't tried it, but I think that serializing from 6.1 to 6.6 should work. Although you might run into issues with custom Fieldtypes that don't exist in 6.6. Other than that I think it should work.

But, if something fails during serializing the content back into V6.6, you don't get a clear error message and have to check in the Sitecore log if there were any issues.

I still prefer creating a package in 6.1 which includes your templates, layouts and content and install it on 6.6.

Comment: I found this article http://www.mikkelhm.dk/post/2012/12/26/Automatic-Sitecore-item-serialization.aspx which was very helpful in enabling serialisation for new items during my migration, then I was able to deserialise those items into 6.6 successfully.

Answer (score 2):

To the best of my knowledge, the serialization format hasn't changed since it was introduced with Sitecore 6.0 (in 2008). The serialization/deserialization process has changed throughout the Sitecore versions though. I have a blog post unofficially documenting the [serialization format](http://seankearney.com/post/Sitecore-Serialization-Format.aspx) here.

[Team Development for Sitecore](http://teamdevelopmentforsitecore.com) uses the Sitecore serialization APIs and we have used the tool to successfully migrate implementations between Sitecore versions. (This isn't technically a supported feature of TDS). So I will say that you should be able to do what you are thinking.

Something that jumps out at me as a potential issue would be if Sitecore changed the shared/unversioned flags of a system level field and one of your .item files had a value for that field. In this case, the .item file would describe an item that wouldn't be deserializable.

Comment: Another issue could be the path length of the serialised items. That would only be an issue if there's a huge content structure and/or items with long names. In this case, Team Development Sitecore Would overcome this issue with file system aliases.

Answer (score -1):

I found this is the better  [Link](http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2012/10/02/migrating-huge-amounts-of-sitecore-content-use-the-sitecore-serializer/) .Hope this is helpfull